# Is this a valid byte string for AES Key?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, utf-8, ascii, decoding

I am working on a little sideproject in Python 3.

My current problem is around AES-based decryption of a file. The content of the file (text) is symmetrical encrypted with AES.

I have imported PyCrypto: https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/

The docs specificy only little regarding the symmetrical key:

> key (byte string) - The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192), or 32 (AES-256) bytes long.

I have the key and looks like:

`0xB0,0x0D,0xDF,0x9D,...` (for security reasons I don't report the complete key here)

Anyway, my first question:

What kind of string is that? It looks like ASCII, but I lack deep knowledge about Encodings. Do I need any kind of transformation / decoding?

I wrote a little program to open a file and decrypt it. But PyCrypto throws an error and I spent now 5 hours with trial and error without any progress:

```
ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long
```

So I tried both:

1. initializing as string:

`key = "0xB0,0x0D,0xDF,0x9D,..."`

and 2. as byte-string:

`key = b"0xB0,0x0D,0xDF,0x9D,..."`

No effect.

Any comments or ideas?

Best Regards,
AFX

Comment: If secret key is some sort of passwords or passphrases, that key is hashed, in order to have random bits.

Comment: Spend a fraction of five hours learning encodings including hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to provide the solution that worked out for me:

First, get the basics:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes

key = 'insert-key-here'
```

Now, I build a method to decrypt:

```
def decrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename=None):
    """ Decrypts a file using AES (CBC mode) with the
        given key.
    """
    backend = default_backend()
    with open(in_filename, mode="r+b") as infile:
        iv = infile.read(16) #Calling .read() will move the iterator exactly as many positions
        cipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend=backend)
        decryptor = cipher.decryptor()
        with open(out_filename, mode="w+b") as outfile:
            cipher_text = infile.read() #Only the first 16byte are the iv, the rest is the cipher-text
            outfile.write(decryptor.update(cipher_text) + decryptor.finalize())
```

Here is the key: I had to transform the key to byte-string first

```
#Transform key to byte-string
key_int = [int(x,0) for x in key.split(',')]
decrypt_byte_key = b''
for x in key_int:
    decrypt_byte_key += x.to_bytes(1, 'little')
```

Finally, you can run it on your file:

```
decrypt_file(decrypt_byte_key, "input.enc", "output.txt")
```

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a hex string.  For example, if you had this:

```
0x0F, 0x10, 0x1A
```

Then this, condensed down to be an actual hex string, is:

```
0F101A
```

Which, as raw bytes, is:

```
15, 16, 26
```

You just need to convert it to a byte array first.  Have a look at `binascii.unhexlify`.